# I'm making an FPS game in unity and keep getting 1 error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

My code works perfectly fine until I tried to run the game where I get this error with a vector3 If anybody knows the answer the help would be greatly appreciated thanks It seems like the code should work but whenever I use the vector 3 completely breaks Unity I'm new to the game development and I'm following along with Tutorial to learn how to use the unity

Assets\movement.cs(48,25): error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform orientation;

    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }



    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {

        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput * orientation.right * horizontalInput;

        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Geeky said "Add horizontal and vertical input, don't multiply it"

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 moveDir;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float moveSpeed;
    void Update()
    {
        moveDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;
        // You can use either AddForce or velocity. AddForce feels kinda like space though.
        rb.AddForce(moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);// Time.deltaTime makes it move at the same speed on even 20fps
        //rb.velocity = moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230148/17235431)? Why don't you post your own answer instead of copying mine? Just coding it in different way doesn't may your answer different than mine

Comment: Sorry, But I coded all of that myself. You were just a bit faster to upload it then me

Comment: Please take a look at the already present answers, then proceed to write your answer. If you found that someone has already posted the answer you were thinking to write, you can't write the same answer, you have to write a different answer. or else it's considered plagiarised

Comment: Well, mine is completly different from yours.. I also tested yours and it didnt even work. And that is probably also why 34bllurh picked mine as the answer. I also simplified their code by a ton

Comment: It works, there's a typo in 34bllurh's code, `"Horizontal"` is written with a small `h`, other than that, it does work

Comment: Oh, Didnt notice that lol

Answer (score 2):

Add horizontal and vertical input, don't multiply it

```cs
private void MovePlayer()
{
    Vector3 moveDirectionY = orientation.forward * verticalInput;
    Vector3 moveDirectionX = orientation.right * horizontalInput;

    rb.AddForce((moveDirectionX + moveDirectionY).normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
}
```